# Multi page redirect

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter with CodeIgniter sessions that are stored in a MySQL database.

I need to do a multi-page redirect as shown below:

```
`some_form.php` -> `processing.php` -> `another_form_based_on_processing.php`
```

Everything's okay going from `some_form.php` -> `processing.php`.

But when I redirect the page from `processing.php` -> `another_form_based_on_processing.php`, I lose the session. An entirely new session is started, and user information and all other session variables are gone.

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: I assume it is not "multipage" redirect, but regular one page redirect from processing.php to  another_form_based_on_processing.php

Comment: The user has no input from processing.php -> another_form_based_on_processing.php so the user should be taken there directly after processing.

Processing should be done ONLY once.

But as soon as I do a redirect('another_page_based_on_processing.php');

I find myself logged out of the application completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes (if the user doesn't have cookies enabled, for example), PHP has to pass the session ID from page to page in the URL... perhaps that's the case here, and when you redirect from the 2nd page to the 3rd (and the user is logged out), that's because the session ID isn't being carried along. Just an idea.

One strategy to debug this that might be easier than watching HTTP headers is to (temporarily) simplify your code dramatically. Right now you say the hop from page 1 to page 2 is okay, but 2 to 3 is where the session is lost... so change page to 2 to immediately redirect to page 3. If, after that change, the user is still logged in on page 3 (i.e. the session is preserved), that means something *else* in your page 2 code is destroying the session.

Good luck, and to echo Col. Shrapnel's comment above, posting code/debugging results may help us to help you more :-)

Comment: p.s. what does your redirect() function look like?

Comment: I didn't get it yet, but you're right. I simplified it and the session is persistent. Which means it's something in the code itself. I'll look for it now.

Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. FWIW I usually find this to be a quick way to home in fast on a bug when I'm not entirely sure where the exact problem lies: I just start hacking away at the code with a machete, (temporarily) removing large chunks of functionality and seeing if the bug still exhibits itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach any problem is debugging based on the knowledge.

In case of sessions, debugging involves HTTP sniffing to watch HTTP headers and cookie among them. What the server does set, and what the browser return. HttpWatch from the ad on this page could help.

I hope both your scripts are on the same domain/server.

Comment: Yes all scripts on the same server.

Comment: well go for the HTTP debugging.
posting here redirect code would be helpful too